# For what exactly @XXXXX is used for?

Tags: java, syntax, jboss

Beginner's question. I see a lot of @XXXXX s in our code base. So I would like to know what is the significance of this syntax.
Below is a snippet of our code and example

```
@Process     
public Message loadManifest(Message message) {
```

How can we relate this to JBoss AS Pipeline?

Comment: take a look https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

Comment: @gubblebozer : My question is also in relation with the RHEL JBoss, how can it fit in there to the pipeline, will edit the  question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an annotation. It's uses vary from preventing warnings during compilation (like @SuppressWarnings), to automation of creating servlet mappings. [This link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/annotations.html) may clarify the concept a bit more.

In case of your particular example, my bet is it's [this one](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossESBActionAnnotations#jive_content_id_Process)

Comment: This actually is Jboss snippet which I have as an example. Thanks your answer is informative.

Answer (score 0):

They are most likely custom [Java Annotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation).

Answer (score 0):

`@Process` is called an annotation. A big part of java is reflection, which is the ability for a class to see the methods and fields of other classes. It is very nice and it has created a lot awesome libraries.

Annotations are accessible through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

@ tags are Annotations

As per Sun, Oracle:
Annotations, a form of metadata, provide data about a program that is not part of the program itself. Annotations have no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate.

Annotations have a number of uses, among them:

```
Information for the compiler — Annotations can be used by the compiler to detect errors or suppress warnings.
Compile-time and deployment-time processing — Software tools can process annotation information to generate code, XML files, and so forth.
Runtime processing — Some annotations are available to be examined at runtime.
```

[Annotations - Oracle reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/)